# How to set up CAS login in WPF application for API calls?

Tags: c#, wpf, single-sign-on, cas

I'm building an application in WPF that is client side and will only depend on external API.
To this point I could use open API which I build in RestSharp and everything worked well. But from last week this API uses CAS authentication, so to use them I need to be authenticated. API I want to call is in external server. They have two API's and my assumption is that if I will log in on their site using CAS then I will be able to use this auth for my API calls for second API.

I'm new to SSO, CAS and security overall, so this was my first thought: I will build WebBrowser control, get returned TGC cookie and use ticket from it to use in requests I will be making. But this failed, setting cookie still got me and 401 error and from what I understand from CAS auth for now, TGC is a go to for checking if I'm an authenticated user in current session?

My next thought was to use some CAS c# library. Unfortunately all of advices / libraries focus on creating CAS in .NET projects. Is there some library which will provide a way to log in to CAS auth and then allow me to make API calls?

I hope this makes sense and I didn't messed up things completely. I'm new to secutity and I will be grateful for any help or guidance how to approach this problem. Things I have: API specification (endpoints paths) and username and password to log in to the system.